# Mac - Can't Take Screenshots With Multiple Monitors

Tags: macos

I recently setup my second monitor for my Mac.

Prior, I could screenshot fine (CMD+Shift+4 , CMD+Shift+3). 
Now, I cannot do that. The sound will play, but the files are not on my Desktop like they were before. I also use a tool called 'Mac2Imgur' which uploads screenshots directly to Imgur, and that doesn't work either (I assume because screenshots themselves don't work).

Any idea on how to fix this?

**edit:**

Dragging an image from Chrome to my Desktop didn't work, so I manually saved the image 'Save Image As...' and then all the screenshots appeared on my Desktop. But, future screenshots didn't appear, and then doing the same thing, they showed up.

Comment: One personal solution I found is an apple script:

repeat
tell application "Finder" to tell desktop to update every item
end repeat

Though, I would much rather like an official fix, then mass refreshing Finder every second (not sure the performance affects that has.)

Answer (score 0):

The location of images can change.  Use this command to determine where the screen shots are going:

`defaults read  com.apple.screencapture location`
This shows my screen capture target is  `/Users/hogstrom/Desktop/` where I expect them to be.  If that is not your location then you can reset it by executing:

`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop/`

Then try again.  This should get the screen shots visible again as they are placed on the Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Mojave 10.14.6 on a MacBook Pro with a couple of Thunderbolt monitors as secondary and tertiary displays.  When I press ++<3>, I get three screenshots placed on the desktop.  When I press ++<4> I get to select the area of the screen that I want to turn into a screenshot.